# Format a specific date in moment

Tags: momentjs

In my react native application, I have a date field it has values like this.
2005-7-16

Now I want to convert this to 'DD/MM/YYYY' format using moment. 
But this gives an error.

```
return moment('2005-7-16').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: What's the error in question ?

Comment: What error does it give?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```js
console.log(moment('2005-7-16', 'YYYY-M-DD').format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse with correct format using moment.

```
moment('2005-7-16', 'YYYY-M-DD').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```